# How to delete an entire line in Visual Studio 2022 for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just switched to macOS and I can't get the shortcuts I'm used to.
On Windows, CTRL + L cut an entire line. I can't figure out how to do it on Mac.

This OS is so frustrating... it seems to be missing all basic keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Under `Tools>Preferences...` menù, on the "Keyboard Shortcuts" sections, you can select a "Visual Studio Windows" scheme and get the same shortcut you are used to under windows.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's Code > Preferences > Keyboard shortcut but we can do it with next shortcut by default:
**Command + X**